# HLSL Textured Light: outputs only a specific part of the texture (new problem)

Tags: xna, textures, hlsl

**Problem 1**

I am trying to create a spotlight that instead of giving the circle within the spotlight a simple color, applies a texture to it. However, where the texture is supposed to be is only a black circle: [image](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxTJskq131LeaEtQV0lWUjQ3RWM/edit?usp=sharing).

Solution: the position I used for my texture wasnt correct.

old and faulty code:

```
float4 TexturedSpotlightPixelShader(VertexShaderOutput input, float2 TextureCoordinate : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0
{   
    //I left out all the other code in the shader, full code is at the bottom of the thread
    color = tex2D(SpotlightTextureSampler, TextureCoordinate); 
}
```

better code that solved my 'black problem (but created a new one):

```
float4 TexturedSpotlightPixelShader(VertexShaderOutput input) : COLOR0
{   
    //I left out all the other code in the shader, full code is at the bottom of the thread
    color = tex2D(SpotlightTextureSampler, input.Position); 
}
```

where at that point input.Position was set to the worldPosition in the vertexshader (which turned out was the reason for problem 2)

**Problem 2**

My spotlight now applies the texture, however the texture is repeated multiple times in miniature, as such: [image](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxTJskq131LecnVZbUNuNmZtd0k/edit?usp=sharing)

Solution:
I added these lines in the vertex shader:

```
input.Position3D.w = 1.0f;
output.Position = mul(viewPosition, Projection);
```

and by adding/changing these lines in the pixelshader:

```
float2 TextureCoordinates;
TextureCoordinates.x =  input.Position.x / input.Position.w / 2.0f + 0.5f;
TextureCoordinates.y = -input.Position.y / input.Position.w / 2.0f + 0.5f;
color += tex2D(SpotlightTextureSampler, TextureCoordinates);
```

however, there was still a third problem.

**Problem 3**

The third and probably (I hope :P) the last problem, my spotlight now only shows a part of my texture and manually resizing the image (in the image file, not in my code) doesnt change what part of the texture is shown, as such: [image](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxTJskq131LeeTVwQTI5WTFoWjA/edit?usp=sharing)

Solution:
In my vertexshader I used the 2D positions (viewmatrix multiplied with the projection matrix) where I should have used a viewmatrix not based from my camera but from my spotlights point of view (and a projection matrix also for my spotlight's point of view)

My new code:

```
float4x4 View2, Projection2;

VertexShaderOutput SimpleVertexShader(VertexShaderInput input)
{
//left out a lot of code here
output.Position = mul(mul(worldPosition, View2), Projection2);
}
```

**Full Code**

Link to the [shader code](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1IWI1oXjHphVRJbeDy9ekVHeG_dNckI3KPpWtEm8eRoA/edit?usp=sharing) and the link to the [xna/c# code](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1G4B50VZJ7l_IFTTK85PZgxVhp15dFFfrErCISFSit5k/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: What happens if instead of going through the branch you immediately `return tex2D(SpotlightTextureSampler, TextureCoordinate);`? If you still see a black circle then your texture could be empty or not being sampled correctly.

Comment: @AvengerDr if I do that I get a completely black model, thats why I think the problem lies indeed in the sampler (or texture), but I have no clue here exactly the problem lies in my code or how to solve it

Comment: My assumption is that either the texture is not being sampled correctly as AvengerDr said or your TextureCoordinates are wrong and constantly fetch a black Pixel.

Comment: Try replacing the texture with a 1x1 magenta (or some other highly visible color) to see if it's coming through at all.  Also try replacing the `TextureCoordinate` with a constant like `float2(0.5, 0.5)` and see if you get the color from the center of your texture.

Comment: @LuisW I tried exchanging the content of the sampler I use for my greyscale with this one, to see if my texture then would somehow show up on the greyscale or something else, as to find out whether the problem might be the TextureCoordinates. To my surprise the greyscaleshader kept working flawlessly, litterally nothing changed. It seems as if the samplers dont do anything or at least if the line Texture = <SpotlightTexture>; does completely nothing. Does maybe the problem lie here: sampler SpotlightTextureSampler = sampler_state? The part after the equation is the same for both samplers.

Comment: @NathanReed exchanging the TextureCoordinate with a constant turned my spotlight from black to yellow, which makes sense because part of the picture is yellow, it might be the coordinates after all :) I should be able to fix that up in the vertexshader. If you want you can post your comment as an answer so I can accept it. And thanks to the others as well, aparently my earlier tests werent solid enough ^^

Comment: @HasseIona Once you've figured out the actual problem with the UVs, you can post it as an answer yourself.  My comment wasn't an solution to the problem, just a debugging tip.

Comment: @NathanReed I have solved the black-problem but now a new problem arose ^^ Instead of the black circle Im getting a circle with lots of miniature copies of my texture (while my texture is quite big) any clue what might have caused that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the world position as the texture coordinates.  Texture coordinates range from 0 to 1 and then the texture repeats itself, so the result of this is that you'll get a copy of the texture squeezed into every 1 unit along the XY axes in world space.  If your world units are centimeters then you'll get a copy of the texture in each square centimeter, for instance.

For a spotlight with a texture, you probably want [projective texturing](http://www.rastertek.com/dx11tut43.html).  The code in that tutorial is for D3D11, so it won't directly work in XNA, but you should be able to adapt it.  The short version is that you have to transform the world position to a coordinate system aligned with the light and divide by z.  This will make the texture scale larger as it gets farther from the light, like the image from a projector.

Comment: That about does the trick :) I'm just having one last problem and that is that the texure I am using only shows up partially: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxTJskq131LeeTVwQTI5WTFoWjA/edit?usp=sharing. I've tried manually resizing the actual image (and then removing and readding it to the project) but that doesnt change anything, even though I reduced the image size to less than half it still shows exactly the same part of the texture. I've updated my shader code in the google document at the bottom of my original post

Comment: @HasseIona Youre projecting the texture using the camera viewfrustrum, but you have to use anotherone to get the effect. In your case you will need to create a frustrum around your spot-lights cone. And by creating a frustrum i mean creating the corresponding view and projection matrices. Look closely at the link nathan posted , it´s all there.

Comment: The link is down, but you can still read it via the Wayback Machine: http://web.archive.org/web/20121105034527/http://www.rastertek.com/dx11tut43.html